# combining different data which have 1 axis in common python numpy, write to table

Tags: python, numpy

I have a set of numpy 2d arrays which all have one axis in common, I wish to put them in order on the same 'table'.

```
a=np.loadtxt('file',unpack=True,dtype='str')
b=np.loadtxt('file',unpack=True,dtype='str')
c=np.loadtxt('file',unpack=True,dtype='str')
d=np.loadtxt('file',unpack=True,dtype='str')
```

from these arrays a[0],b[0],c[0],d[0] are all times, and a[1],b[1],c[1] and d[1] and values of different things.  i wish to put them all on the same axis. I also wish to put Nan values in where there are no values from the arrays. For example In the end i will get a table like the one below. Is there an easy way to do this in python? The problem is a,b,c,d are all different lengths, so I need to put in NANS where some of the variables dont have values, time also needs to be generated from all 4 variables.

```
time  a    b     c    d
t1    Nan  value nan  nan
t2    value nan  nan   nan
t3    value nan value nan
t4    nan nan value nan
t5    value nan value value
t6    nan nan value value
t7    nan nan nan value
t8    nan nan value nan
t9    nan nan value value
```

Answer (score 0):

Pandas might not be fast for matrix operation but it's good for generating "table":

```
import pandas as pd

d = {'time'= a[0],'a':a[1],'b':b[1],'c':c[1],'d':d[1]}  # give column name to each column where your numpy arrays have same axis
df=pd.DataFrame(data=d)
```

I think pandas fills Nan automatically where data is missing